# unexpected result from PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console, phantomjs

I am trying to write a [PhantomJS](https://phantomjs.org) script to check some security issues in some websites. I am adding the __domlog function to the window object, which should be called when i pass this URL for example:

```
https://domgo.at/cxss/example/1?payload=abcd&sp=x#1</iframe></style></script></object></embed></textarea><img src=x onerror=__domlog(0,0,51)><!--/*
```

This is the code:

```
function validateExploit(url, callback) {
    console.log('Validating ..');

    var page = require('webpage').create();

    page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg, lineNum, sourceId) {
        console.log('CONSOLE: ' + msg + ' (from line #' + lineNum + ' in "' + sourceId + '")');
    };

    page.onCallback = function (data) {
        result = data;
        console.log(' -> Exploit successful');
    };

    page.onInitialized = function () {
        page.evaluateJavaScript('function(){location.href = decodeURI(location.href);}');
        page.customHeaders = { "X-XSS-Protection": "0" };
        page.evaluate(function () {
            window.__domlog = function (findingId, exploitId, tabId) {
                window.callPhantom({
                    'success': true,
                    'findingId': findingId,
                    'exploitId': exploitId,
                    'tabId': tabId
                });
            };
        });
    };

    page.open(url, function (status) {
        page.close();
        callback(result);
        console.log(' -> Page closed. Exploit found: ' + result.success);
    });
}
```

The problem is that this function isn't called, and the page.onConsoleMessage doesn't show any error. When i request the same link in Chrome, the __domlog function will be requested. As far as i know, phantomJS is based on Chrome, i wanted to ask if i did some error.